# Losing Gesture Recognizers in UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipopovercontroller, gesture-recognition

I have a class called PhotoBoothController that I use to manipulate an image using gestures. It works fine when I run it on iPhone. However when I run it on iPad, I display the PhotoBoothController inside a UIPopoverController. The image appears fine, however I can't manipulate it as my gestures don't appear to be recognized. I'm not sure how to make the UIPopoverController take control of the gestures.

I present the popovercontroller and configure the view thus:

```
- (void)presentPhotoBoothForPhoto:(UIImage *)photo button:(UIButton *)button {

    //Create a photoBooth and set its contents
    PhotoBoothController *photoBoothController = [[PhotoBoothController alloc] init];
    photoBoothController.photoImage.image = [button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //set up all the elements programmatically.
    photoBoothController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //Add frame (static)
    UIImage *frame = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"HumptyLine1Frame.png"] adjustForResolution];
    UIImageView *frameView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:frame];
    frameView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [photoBoothController.view addSubview:frameView];

    //Configure image
    UIImageView *photoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photo];
    photoView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, photo.size.width, photo.size.height);
    photoBoothController.photoImage = photoView;

    //Add canvas
    UIView *canvas = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameView.frame];
    photoBoothController.canvas = canvas;
    [canvas addSubview:photoView];
    [canvas becomeFirstResponder];

    [photoBoothController.view addSubview:canvas];
    [photoBoothController.view bringSubviewToFront:frameView];

    //resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
    photoBoothController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(frameView.frame.size.width+100, frameView.frame.size.height+400);

    self.photoBooth = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:photoBoothController];
    [self.photoBooth presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame
                                     inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
}
```

I thought `[canvas becomeFirstResponder]` might do it but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Any advice much appreciate, thank you.

UPDATE: adding code as per comment

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if (!_marque) {
    _marque = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    _marque.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _marque.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    _marque.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    _marque.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    _marque.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
    _marque.bounds = CGRectMake(photoImage.frame.origin.x, photoImage.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
    _marque.position = CGPointMake(photoImage.frame.origin.x + canvas.frame.origin.x, photoImage.frame.origin.y + canvas.frame.origin.y);
  }
  [[self.view layer] addSublayer:_marque];

  UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
  [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

  UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
  [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
  [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
  [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [canvas addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfileImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
  [tapProfileImageRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [tapProfileImageRecognizer setDelegate:self];
  [canvas addGestureRecognizer:tapProfileImageRecognizer];

}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
  return ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] && ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]];
}
```

Comment: Please add the code used to attach the gesture recognizer(s) to your UIPopoverController

Comment: @stavash done - the code is in the PhotoBoothController class. Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting issue. How about adding the gestures externally to the UIPopoverController? I know it requires quite a few changes but I don't have any other suggestions right now...

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a similar application, and i can easily manipulate images on the canvas.

1) Check if the **userInteractionEnabled** property of the canvas is set to **YES**.
2) You can try adding the gestures to the ImageView's rather than the canvas. (I am guessing u want to zoom , rotate n swipe the images).

Answer (score 1):

some guesses:

1. is this because `viewDidLoad` method have been called before cavas property been set? In this case, you could try to add recognizers after present popover in another method such as `viewDidAppear`.
2. I also agree that the key may be that UIPopoverController allows interaction to other views outside of the popover. So i suggest to move `[canvas becomeFirstResponder];` to the end of the `viewDidLoad` method in `PhotoBoothController` and try `self.view becomeFirstResponder` here because you actually add recognizers to self.view.